# RecyclerView leaving a small gap at end

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a RecyclerView(RV) in my DialogBox which displays data fetched from JSON file. Problem is, my RV is leaving a small gap at end. But it fills and displays correctly when scrolled. These pictures will explain everything well..On first launch, views aren't taking up the whole width..but after being scrolled(just scrolling up and down back) it gets fixed.

[image: on first launch]

[image: after being scrolled]

This is my ViewHolder

```
 public MyDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    MyDataAdapter.ViewHolder vh;
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.creds_cardview, parent, false);
    vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

Comment: What does R.layout.creds_cardview and your viewholder layout file look like?

Comment: you need to edit your XML layout marginTop, and it will work perfectly.